# unused memory using 32 bit integer in C

Tags: c++, c, integer, packing

I have the folowing struct of integers (32 bit environment):

```
struct rgb {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};
```

Am I correct in saying that, since rgb component values (0-255) only require 8-bits(1 byte) to be represented, I am only using 1 byte of memory and leaving 3 bytes unused for each component?

Also, if I instead did the following:

```
struct rgb{
    unsigned int r:8;
    unsigned int g:8;
    unsigned int b:8;
};
```

Assuming that what I said above is correct, would using this new struct reduce the number of unused bytes to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `unsigned char`, which is exactly what you need. Like

```
#ifndef BYTE
#define BYTE unsigned char
#endif

struct rgb
{
    BYTE r;
    BYTE g;
    BYTE b;
};
```

But to answer your question - yes, it does reduce the number of bytes to 1 for each field.

<strike>Anyway, the struct will probably be with size of 4B, because of the alignment (but these are details and it's completely platform specific)</strike> removed, thanks to @JimBuck's comment

Comment: Actually, no, in this case, since all elements are chars, no padding is needed since it is already char-aligned, so it will be a 3-byte struct.

Comment: @JimBuck - whooops, I missed the part with "all elements". You'r damn right, thanks! :)

Comment: @Kiril - almost, although the struct will be only 3 bytes, the next object is going to be aligned on 32bits so it really uses 4bytes

Comment: @MartinBeckett - yes, I _completely_ agree with this. Thanks for the note

Comment: @MartinBeckett - it depends what that "next object" is. If it's another `rgb` struct or some other char-based struct, it will be put packed next to the `rgb` struct. But, more importantly, if you have an array of `rgb`s (very common in games, for example), they'll be packed As You Would Hope(tm).

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is correct. The second solution will essentially break down the struct to a single int with 8bits for each member.

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct rgb{
    unsigned int r:8;
    unsigned int g:8;
    unsigned int b:8;
};

int main(void) {
        printf("Size of RGB: %d", sizeof(struct rgb));
        return 0;
}
```

This will output: "Size of RGB: 4". But as others have suggested it will be best to use a datatype that comes with 8bits, ergo: `unsigned char`.

Comment: there is no byte datatpe in C

Comment: Indeed, there isn't. I forgot about the context for a second there, fixed it to `unsigned char`

Answer (score 2):

Integers are 32 bit -> 4 bytes. I would use unsigned char instead, which is only 1 byte containing values 0-255.

Using typedef to define a new name for the type makes it more convenient to use.

```
typedef unsigned char t_byte;

struct rgb {
    t_byte r;
    t_byte g;
    t_byte b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned int is still the same size, you want unsigned char

```
struct rgb{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};
```

However, you should remember that the standard does not enforce they are not larger -- they may be bigger anyway.  You might need to use a packed pragma to get exactly the alignment you want.

You could also use `unsigned char rgb[3]`

Answer (score 1):

In the first sample you are allocating 4 bytes per color component. For 8 bit color you should allocate just a single byte by using unsigned char. No need for bitfields here.

Note that you have defined a 24 bit pixel here. You may need to add padding if you are using 32 bit pixels.